# Execution time in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, business-intelligence

I ran my packages in a loop and I would like to have execution time of each loop iteration. Now (in Execution Results) I only have elapsed time for Sequence Container, for whole loop (not for every itearation). It's possible to increase level of time granularity?

I ran SSIS package from VS (I can't deploy SSIS project on server). I use SQL Server 2008R2.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a custom loging mechanism. You can simple add a new derived column component and add a time span for each iteration.

Comment: There is no DMV for it?